# How to Convert UIImage (PNG) to a BMP in (B/W = 1 bit)

Tags: swift, image, uiimage

How can I convert an Image which is a PNG in Assets.xcassets "nummer4_2-1b"

So an Image as BMP only black& white and send it to a function
Sending just the PNG causes an error. and the eink needs a BMP

```
let image = UIImage(named: "nummer4_2-1b")

func send(_ image: UIImage?) {
    NFCTagReader.sharedSingleton().send(image!, einkSizeType: .type420)
}
send(image)
```

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-desaturate-an-image-to-make-it-black-and-white try this

Comment: @Arun this would result in a grayscale image not a bw image (1bit)

Comment: @Arun ans it also keeps it as PNG in monochrome... i need as result a B/W BMP File

Comment: @BigAL82 Have you managed to fix imageThresholdCompressedData error?